# Sign Extension Implementation in C

Tags: c, sign-extension

Ok I have read a lot about sign extension but I am brand new to C as well as all the 'bitwise operators' so I am still having trouble figuring out how I should actually implement it in C.

I have a function called `getField` that should return the value of a chunk of bits within a larger bit. It takes three integers: `value`, `hi`, and `lo` plus a bool: `isSigned` as parameters. For Example this call should return 2:

```
return getField(9, 5, 2, 0);
```

My function works except when the number is signed. After reading up on sign extension I think it is my understanding that if `isSigned` is `true` then I need to add ones to the bit so in the example above, the solution (`0010`) would become (`111...0010`). Here is my the code dealing with making numbers signed (`result` is equal to what the function would return if `isSigned` was `false`):

```
if (isSigned) {
    return (~result) + 1;
}
```

This would work if I was supposed to return the 2s complement signed integer but sadly that is not what I am supposed to do. Any assistance is appreciated.

Edit: Here is the entire code for the method...

```
int getField (int value, int hi, int lo, bool isSigned) {
int mask;

//Make Sure 'hi' is the high value
if (hi < lo) {
    int temp = hi;
    hi = lo;
    lo = temp;
}
int numberOfBits = (hi - lo) + 1;

mask = ((1 << numberOfBits) - 1) << lo;
int result = value & mask;

//Get rid of LSB if value is zero
result = result >> lo;

if (isSigned) { //Sign Extension instead of Twos Complement
    return (~0) << numberOfBits | result;
}
else {
    return result;
}
```

}

*(Note: I did see a post similar to this and I read it, but I was still left very confused so I decided to write a different one. Sorry if this is against the rules.)*

Comment: what does the code of `getField` looks like?

Answer (score -1):

So I don't really understand what your function is doing but you could get your answer by the following bitwise operations:

```
int ones = ~0;                  // should give 1111...111111
int shifted_ones = (ones << 4); // should give 1111...110000
result = shifted_ones | result; // should give 1111...110010

// or in one line
result = ((~0) <<4) | result;
```

I'm not sure if this answers your question. Obviously the number of shifts would need to be a variable.

**EDIT**

Ok so the first answer while mathematically correct does give a warning (at least with GCC). The compiler detects bits (1s) shifting off the end of the number. Probably not really a production solution but kinda fun. The original solution doesn't have that warning.

```
int ones = 0b1111; // make the number of ones the same size as the answer.
result = ~ones | result;
```

Comment: Would what you did be equivalent to `result = (~0) << numberOfBits | result`? With number of bits being the `numberOfBits` in  result?

Comment: There was a warning in the answer. I made a note about it.

Answer (score -1):

You should probably use the machines own capability of doing sign extension, which you do with a bit of casting of the data types

```
int getField(unsigned int data, int from, int to, int s)
{
    // assuming 32 bit ints, add error check, ymmw
    data <<= 32-from;
    if (s)
       return ((int)data) >> (32-(from-to));
    return (data >> (32-(from-to)));
}
```

Comment: Conversion from unsigned to signed integers is implementation defined. Also your code invokes undefined behaviour for `from == 0` or other values if `unsigned has less than 32 bits. The right shift is implementation defined, too. there is no guarantee the sign will be copied, etc.